# Control Windows permissions on Samba share from linux

Tags: active-directory, permissions, samba4

I have a Debian 8 with Samba 4 as a AD domain member. The DC is Windows Server 2008. The shares are able to handle Windows permissions - I use IDMAP backend = rid, since I cannot add uidNumber and gidNumber to AD account record.

I can display and set ACL permissions with `getfacl` and `setfacl`, but the R-W-X settings cannot set fine-grade Windows permissions (take ownership, read attributes, set permissions, full control...)

So, is there a possibility to manage (or at least show) advanced Windows permissions of shared file/folder from Linux?

The point is, I would like to make a script, which periodically checks all shared files, if they have the permissions I would like to have them. And alert, if something is wrong, so it would be some type of live documentation check of desired privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found out myself.

The Windows permissions are stored in "Extended attributes". The raw data of these attributes can be displayed by `xattr` from Debian package `python-xattr`:

`xattr -l <local_path>`

To display and manipulate these permissions, you can use `smbcacls` from Debian package `smbclient`:

`smbcacls //localhost/share <path_within_share>`

In the output of the command above, there are some cryptic values like CI,OI,I,FULL,... Great explanation of these values is here: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2010-June/071390.html